# What are all ways of unexpected exits in iOS

Tags: ios, crash

My app is not allowed to be run in the Background.
I save flag `unexpectedExit` in the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and clear flag `unexpectedExit` in next methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

What is possible reason for missing clearing flags?

I know about next:

1. some jailbroken staff - i detect jailbroken device and ignore any crash from them
2. Crash created by user (with 0x00000000deadfa11 code) - long pressing lock button until UI changed + long pressing home button - until crash. This type of crash impossible when proximity sensor is ON.
3. manual reboot device - long pressing lock + home button simultaneously. This also impossible when proximity sensor is ON.
4. Battery discharge. I see when battery is 0 - it happens direct poweroff with exiting of application. I track battery charge
5. crashes which can be handled by CrashLytics or PLCrashReporter or similar
6. Crash related with [low](https://opensource.plausible.coop/jira/browse/PLCR-478) [memory](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/123408-do-you-catch-out-of-memory-crashes-). according [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) app should be able handle it with

   (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application;
7. Crash [generated by watchdog](https://opensource.plausible.coop/jira/browse/PLCR-477) (with 0x8badf00d code) also unhandled by any crash tools (as i know), and i don't know any way to catch this. Do you know?

Reality shows me that i miss something. What it can be?
Are there any mistakes in my suggestions above?

Comment: See a list of some notable [exception codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-ANALYZING_CRASH_REPORTS-EXCEPTION_CODES).

Comment: Thank you @Rob for mention this - i fix my question to be more clear that my app is not support Background so exceptions from link is not applicable for me. Exception is: 0xc00010ff - but i hope this type of crashes should be handled by Crashlytics and PLCrashReporter

Comment: That's the "Cool Off" exception (and is listed on the linked page). It means the device is overheating. It says: The exception code 0xc00010ff indicates the app was killed by the operating system in response to a thermal event. This may be due to an issue with the particular device that this crash occurred on, or the environment it was operated in. For tips on making your app run more efficiently, see [iOS Performance and Power Optimization](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=312) with Instruments WWDC session.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered attaching a [mach exception handler](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-11-mach-exception-handlers.html) and a [signal handler](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-04-01-signal-handling.html), and using that to set your flags? Asking for a complete list of all ways an application can be terminated in iOS seems like something that can never be answered - every release has the potential of adding new exceptions, changing an exception code, or responding to unix signals differently. What exactly are you trying to achieve with your flags?

Comment: My flags allow me to know when unexpected exit happens. It allow me to think "what can i do to prevent any unexpected exits". I develop alarm clock. So if unexpected exit happens while app is active then customer will be awaked only with local notification. So when any unexpected exit happens - user asked by app - to send log to developer for analysis. So for every 100k runs of application i have 10 email when this issue appears. 1 email - have issue when alarm was enabled, so my customers was awaked by local notification only (9 email related with jailbreak, etc).

Comment: about handler that you mention: As i understand they used by Crashlytics and PLCrashReporter.